# Pass url parameter to qUnit test using Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, qunit

I'm trying to test a JS file using qUnit automatically from Grunt.  My Grunt task follows:

```
  qunit: {
      a: 'dev/ca/js-tests/test1.html',
      b: 'dev/ca/js-tests/test2.html',
      c: 'dev/ca/js-tests/test2.html?status=approved'
  },
```

Test "a" and "b" run fine, but once I try to pass in a URL parameter in tests "c"  I get the error:

```
Running "qunit:c" (qunit) task
Warning: 0/0 assertions ran (0ms) Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Using "--force" doesn't resolve.  My JS needs the argument passed in - how can I accomplish this from Grunt?

Comment: Hmm... not sure, but have you tried the full `options` object with the `urls` set? [See this example on their Github page](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit#testing-via-http-or-https). That's just a guess, I don't know why the query string wouldn't work in the shorthand form.

Comment: That did work.  Thanks jakerella, put this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Ha! I'm kinda surprised... I don't have any idea why those two formats should be interpreted differently. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as an answer from my comment, but honestly, it's unfortunate that it should have to be this way...

It looks like you'll have to use the full `options` object with the `urls` set. [See this example on their Github page](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-qunit#testing-via-http-or-https). And here it is with your example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  qunit: {
    a: {
      options: {
        urls: [ 'http://localhost/dev/ca/js-tests/test1.html' ]
      }
    },
    b: {
      options: {
        urls: [ 'http://localhost/dev/ca/js-tests/test2.html' ]
      }
    },
    c: {
      options: {
        urls: [ 'http://localhost/dev/ca/js-tests/test2.html?status=approved' ]
      }
    }
  }
});
```